Cannot pull image from ACR Kubernetes
I'm trying to pull an image from ACR but I always keep getting this error
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  22s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/deployment-name-8659d4b797-c6wcx to minikube
  Normal   BackOff    19s               kubelet            Back-off pulling image "somename.azurecr.io/someimage:latest"
  Warning  Failed     19s               kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    6s (x2 over 21s)  kubelet            Pulling image "somename.azurecr.io/someimage:latest"
  Warning  Failed     4s (x2 over 19s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "somename.azurecr.io/someimage:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Head "https://somename.azurecr.io/v2/someimage/manifests/latest": unauthorized: authentication required, visit https://aka.ms/acr/authorization for more information.
  Warning  Failed     4s (x2 over 19s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull

Here is my deployment-name.yml file
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: appname-deployment
    labels:
        app: appname
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: appname
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: appname
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: appname
                  image: somename.azurecr.io/someimage:latest
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 8082
                  env:
                      - name: CORE_PORT
                        valueFrom:
                            configMapKeyRef:
                                name: my-config-map
                                key: CORE_PORT

            imagePullSecrets:
                - name: wc1

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: appname-service
spec:
    selector:
        app: appname
    ports:
        - protocol: TCP
          port: 8082
          targetPort: 8082


I know this question has been asked many times, but I still can't figure out.
Surprisingly, docker pull somename.azurecr.io/someimage:latest works really fine.
I have tried

using servicePrincipal name with https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-kubernetes.
Also for the above, I tried directly using admin access (username and password) from Access Keys menu in Azure

The command to create a secret for #2 was
kubectl create secret docker-registry wc1 \
    --docker-server=somename.azurecr.io \
    --docker-username=somename \
    --docker-password=admin_password

Can somebody point me what will fix that error?

It's an authentication issue - does the service principal have AcrPull role assigned?

@RuiJarimba, yes I did see on the console that I received AcrPull access. However, what I wasn't sure was what value should go to SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME. I tried putting the application id, but I am unsure if that is correct

Double-check if the kubectl create secret command is creating the secret in the right namespace, i.e. the one where you're deploying your resources to - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-auth-kubernetes#create-an-image-pull-secret

@RuiJarimba, I have pushed my image in somename.azurecr.io/someimage:latest. So should my namespace be ,empty or default or root?

I'm mentioning the kubernetes namespaces. Are you deploying your application to a specific namespace? If you're not specifying the namespace when running kubectl commands then it is probably using the default namespace

What I'm trying to say is that the docker-registry secret and your deployment need to be in the same namespace.

Ok, in my case it's default then

AKS integration
In case you're using Azure CLI, you can integrate an existing ACR with an existing AKS cluster using the az aks update command with the --attach-acr parameter:
# Attach using acr-name
az aks update --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup --attach-acr <acr-name>

# Attach using acr-resource-id
az aks update --name myAKSCluster --resource-group myResourceGroup --attach-acr <acr-resource-id>

The az aks update --attach-acr command uses the permissions of the user running the command to create the ACR role assignment. This role is assigned to the kubelet managed identity.
See Authenticate with Azure Container Registry (ACR) from Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) for more details.

Right now I am trying to use acr and kubernetes deployment to pull the private images. Is using the aks a necessity here?

@Chilarai sorry I was assuming you were using AKS, my bad. Which kind of kubernetes cluster are you using?

I am trying it using minikube locally. If successful, I will move to aks. That's the plan
